# My String.split() function is not running properly and I don't know why?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

```
public class fake {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      String s = "i.like.this.program.very.much";
      String arr[] = s.split(".");
      int n = arr.length;
              
      System.out.println(n);
    }
```

my output is coming '0'

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the dot (.) character, And why you need to do this is because(.) is the special character in Java Regular Expression

```
          String s = "i.like.this.program.very.much";
          String arr[] = s.split("\\.");
          int n = arr.length;
                  
          System.out.println(n);
```

Another way could be :

```
      String s = "i.like.this.program.very.much";
      String arr[] = s.split("[.]");
      int n = arr.length;
              
      System.out.println(n);
```